# Is this a touring bike?

Tags: identify-this-bike

[image: pic]

I’m thinking to buy this bike. I usually ride mountain bikes and this is my first time looking for a touring bike. I only need something for ride on the roads to go school.

Could someone recommend me something??

Info:

- 10 Speed CCM Ladies Bicycle
- 25" Rims diameter
- 21" or 53cm Frame Size
- Women's road bike sizing
- Rider Height 55" - 58" / 165cm - 172cm
- Frame Size 53cm - 55cm
- Frame Size Medium

Comment: Any bike can be a touring bike, even a kids tricycle. You just have to tour on it. You could tour on this bike but it might be uncomfortable and the bike might not last a few thousand km.

Comment: Note that the bike dates from about 1970.  It's sort of a "mixte" style -- not quite a "women's" frame, not ideal for loaded touring.  The tires are ultra-narrow, not good for loaded touring either, and really only good if you're trying to race.  For a road bike used to commute 10 miles or so it's OK but far from ideal.

Comment: Please answer in answers

Comment: @DanielRHicks I thought the characteristic of a "mixte" was that the top tube continued right through to the rear drop-outs, rather than stopping at the seat tube. What's making you say this isn't quite a women's frame? it looks like one to me.

Comment: How far is your ride to school?

Comment: If you end up buying the bike, consider moving shift levers to down tube. Installed where they are they will stab you in the abdomen in accidents.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - The "mixte" design went through a number of iterations.  A true women's (girl's) frame had parallel downtubes.  Both are pretty much passe anymore, especially the woman's style, as that design greatly weakened the frame.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Eh, those are pretty much parallel.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a touring bike: touring bikes would have mounts for front and rear racks, as well as mudguards.  This bike has mudguard mounts (the little "eyes" near the front and rear axles) but no rack mounts.  Rack mounts would be bigger versions of the same things near the axles, and also mounting points near the saddle and at the top of the forks.

Honestly, though, don't focus on the name. You say that you need a bike to cycle to school, so focus on finding a bike that will be suitable for that.

- If you don't want to carry a rucksack while you ride (which can get quite sweaty in hot weather), you'll need something that has mounting points for a rack.
- Unless rain is rare where you live, you'll want something that has mounting points for mudguards.
- Assuming you're riding on roads or paved/gravel cyle trails, you won't need suspension or knobbly tyres.
- If your ride is quite long (say, more than about 15km each way), you'll probably want something with drop handlebars to give yourself more hand positions for comfort; if your ride is fairly short (say, 10km or less; yes, I know I've left a gap in the middle), it won't much matter what kind of bars it has. For longer rides, you'd probably also want a bottle cage, though you can get cages that mount with a strap around one of the tubes, instead of screwing into mounting points.
- For commuting, you might want to replace whatever tyres come with whatever bike you buy, and get something more puncture resistant. Being 45 minutes late for class because you got a puncture (in the rain; it's always in the rain) is no fun at all.

Comment: "in the rain; it's always in the rain"
I beg to differ - of the many flats I had in years and years and years of riding, none  was in the rain :)

Comment: You could also use a seatpost-mounted rack to avoid a sweaty back.  These tend to have lower weight limits but would be fine for a pannier with a change of clothes, bike tools, and even a small laptop

Comment: @CalinCeteras You're either very lucky or a liar! :)

Comment: @DavidRicherby: I don't ride in rain, I use either car or public transport - so it's about maneuvering probabilities ;)

Comment: @CalinCeteras OK, so you're not lucky and not a liar, just a wimp. :D

Answer (score 2):

No that's not really a touring bike.

I'd call it a vintage road bike from the 70s or 80s, dating from the big Bike Boom created by the oil crisis of the 1970s.

You could absolutely ride it anywhere you like, but it probably has 27" wheels which is ETRTO size 630, and they're a bit less common nowdays.

Its got some kind of centerpull brake calipers, which implies medium or above in terms of overall quality.  Possibly has steel rims still which are not as good in the rain as modern alloy rims.   The secondary brake levers will be rubbish at stopping you, and in the bike boom riding on hoods and drops was relatively uncommon for people who weren't racing.

A touring bike would have more places to mount racks, mudguards fitted, and sometimes multi-position handlebars for rest and variety.  Places to pack things on the bike too, like frame bags and bar bags etc to carry your touring kit.... touring riders don't generally wear backpacks.  This bike doesn't have a bottle cage, and I'd bet it lacks bottle cage mounts, dating from the era when hydrating while riding was uncool.

In short - get a leg over it and test ride for a bit.  Then make a decision about how it feels.   Still - a very nice bike, should do the school trip fine, and is less likely to be stolen than an expensive-looking newish MTB or road bike.

Comment: I'm not sure about the theft risk.  It looks rather attractive - bikes like that can fetch a fair bit from those interested in looks

Comment: @ChrisH It's rather old-looking. It'll surely be parked next to newer, shinier bikes with full suspension and knobbly tyres that are much cooler and much easier for the thief to sell.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, maybe, but retro seems to be in at the moment and it looks very well kept.

Answer (score 1):

By the look of it, it has 20mm tires, which would suggest an internal pressure (depending on rider weight) of 7-9 atm. Kick sometime a bus or truck tire. That's 7 to 9 atm for you.
I went from 20 to 23 mm tires, and it made a large difference in comfort, grip and rideability.

As for buy/not buy, ride it a bit - you might love it or you might hate it, and either is fine. Anyway, for anything up to a couple of hours ride it should do fine.

Also, nice conversation opener :)